# type signature for a function that makes a list of lists?

Tags: list, haskell

```
bundle :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
bundle 0 _ = []
bundle n (x:xs) = [x:bundle (n-1) xs]
```

My goal is to do something like this

`bundle 3 [1,2,3,4,5] = [[1,2,3]]`

The code is giving me the error

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘a’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for bundle :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `bundle 3 [1,2,3,4,5] = [[1,2,3]]`?

Answer (score 3):

```
bundle :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
bundle 0 _ = []
bundle n (x:xs) = [x:bundle (n-1) xs]
```

`bundle (n-1) xs` has type `[[a]]`. For `x : bundle (n-1) xs` to make sense, `x` must be an element of `[[a]]`, so it must be an  `[a]`. But it is simply an `a`.

In other words, you are attempting to build an ill-formed list such as

```
[ 1 , [2,3] , [4,5] ]
  ^-- not a list
```

Do you really want to build a `[[a]]`? Isn't an `[a]` more appropriate for your goal?

Answer (score 1):

Chi wrote a bit about the problem - I start at your example and see where it leads me.

I honestly don't understand why you want the second warping but the easiest way you can get this going would be:

```
bundle :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
bundle 0 _ = [[]]
bundle n (x:xs) = let [xs'] = bundle (n-1) xs in [x : xs']
```

of course this will give you `[[]]` for ´bundle 0 ...` but I think that's indeed what you want

Now of course there are some easier ways - for example there is already a function that does something similar: `take` - it just does not wrap the second time but this you can do with a simple `return`:

```
bundle :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
bundle n = return . take n
```

Comment: why the monadic `return` and not just `bundle n x = [take n x]`?

Comment: because I wanted the *point free* version (in this case I think borderline more readable - but that might be opinionated) (also spfrnd did this afterwards)